# how can I use vscode on windows to remote debug launch a linux based project writen by c++ and built by makefile?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, remote-debugging

Background:

1. I am using vscode on windows to remote debug a linux based server project writen by c++ and built by makefile;
2. the Binary executable files made by the makefile could be launched by shell or scripts:
   ./executable_files projects.cfg, and the projects.cfg is a file to tell the project some parameters like port, time_out etc.
3. task.json:

   ```json
   {
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "tasks": [
       {
           "label": "clean",
           "type": "shell",
           "command": "make",
           "args": [
               "clean"
           ],
           "problemMatcher": [],
           "group": "build"
       },
       {
           "label": "make",
           "type": "shell",
           "command": "make",
           "problemMatcher": [],
           "group": {
               "kind": "build",
               "isDefault": true
           }
       }
   ]
   }
   ```
4. launch.json

   ```json
   {
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": "(gdb) 启动",
           "type": "cppdbg",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "${workspaceFolder}/executable_files",
           "args": [        
               "-c",
               "${workspaceFolder}/projects.cfg"
           ],
           "stopAtEntry": false,
           "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
           "environment": [],
           "externalConsole": true,
           "MIMode": "gdb",
           "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
           "setupCommands": [
               {
                   "description": "为 gdb 启用整齐打印",
                   "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                   "ignoreFailures": true
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
   }
   ```
5. I have already set a breakpoints at the entry of the main function

Problems:
when I hit the F5 to debug this projects, it can not even go into the main function, and the debug function do not work to debug by step
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBxCH.jpg)

Help:
so how can I fix this probelm?

Comment: what is the added value of the image

Comment: when I launch to debug,  the five button on the left like "pause", "debug by step" are gray and could not to work

Comment: if it is the debug panel why capture all the rest of your screen